# Restart entire SVG animateTransform sequence?

Tags: html, svg, jquery-animate, repeat, restart

I have a SVG graphic that I am animating via `animateTransform`. It animates in, then stays on screen until you click it, then it scales down to 0 and cannot be brought back. What I want to do is restart the entire animation sequence over say 2 seconds after the last animation has ended (scaled to 0), so it will animate back in.

How can I do this? Thanks!

```
<!-- Keep scaled at 0 on load -->
<animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="0" 
    to="0"
    dur="0.5s"/>
<!-- Scale up after 0.5 seconds -->
<animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="0" 
    to="1"  
    begin="0.5s"    
    dur="0.3s"
    fill="freeze"
    additive="sum"/>
<!-- Scale down on click -->
<animateTransform id="animatFinished"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="1" 
    to="0" 
    begin="click" 
    dur="0.6s"
    fill="freeze"
    additive="sum"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to start the first transform both at time 0 and 2 seconds after the onclick animation has ended which gives us `begin="0s;animatFinished.end+2s"`

The second animation needs to start when the first has ended otherwise it will only fire once.

And the use of additive="sum" is giving you problems as the animations end up trying to add a scale to something which has a scale of 0 which does nothing as 0 x value = 0.

So, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<!-- Keep scaled at 0 on load -->
<animateTransform id="one"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="0" 
    to="0"
    begin="0s;animatFinished.end+2s"
    dur="0.5s"
    fill="freeze"/>
<!-- Scale up after 0.5 seconds -->
<animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="0" 
    to="1"  
    begin="one.end"
    dur="0.3s"
    fill="freeze"/>
<!-- Scale down on click -->
<animateTransform id="animatFinished"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML" 
    type="scale" 
    from="1" 
    to="0" 
    begin="click" 
    dur="0.6s"
    fill="freeze"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the animateTransform element(s) you want to restart and use beginElement() method

```js
const animateEl = document.querySelector("#animatFinished");
animateEl.beginElement();
```